# Find out API ID for API Auto Discovery in Anypoint API Manager 1

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I have an application built in Anypoint 7.1 using Mule 4.1.3 and have deployed it successfully in runtime manager.

I want to setup API auto discovery but have found that the API Manager looks like it is still on version 1 and not 2 as I cannot see the API ID.

How can I setup API auto discovery in this scenario as I need the API ID to set it up in the project and Anypoint Studio 7.1 does not provide the fields that I used to use to set up API auto discovery in Mule 3.8.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In [Mule 4, Autodiscovery mechanism](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/v/2.x/api-auto-discovery-new-concept) is quite different from Mule 3. Instead of API name and version, it uses API ID. Tag name changes also. In addition to that, in order to succeed "linking" your flow with the corresponding API defined in API Manager, API instance must be previously created there.

Example:

```
..
xmlns:api-gateway="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway"
..
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway/current/mule-api-gateway.xsd
..
<api-gateway:autodiscovery apiId="1234" flowRef="myFlow" />
..
```

1234 = ID of the API instance

"myFlow" = Flow to link to the API instance

Studio 7.1 provides the option to specify autodiscovery. Please, look for it in the Global Elements tab of your XML.

Also, Mule 4 only works with organizations created after November 2017 or migrated to the new model. You should request migrating your pre November 2017 organization to the new model if you'd like to use Mule v4.x. Mule v3.8.x and Mule v3.9.x can work with pre and post November 2017 release type organizations.